# How to get the velocity and work of an Inelastic Collision Problem

Tags: classical-mechanics, momentum, collision

A moving truck strikes a car parked on the street. During the collision the vehicles stick together and slide across the street until they stop. The moving truck has a total mass of 1980 kg (including driver), the parked car has a total mass of 960.0 kg. The vehicles slide 10.5 m before coming to rest. Assume a frictional coefficient between the vehicles and the street of 0.350.

### a) How much work does it need to slide the vehicle across the street?
b) What was the velocity of the two vehicles directly after impact?
c) What was the original velocity of the truck before the impact?

This is not a HW problem, this is an exercise for preparing for my physics exam.

So, I tried to solve the work done by this equation: Fk= μ * m * g
and then substitute the resulted force with this equation: W= F cosθ * d

is that right? I'm also confused by the second and third questions, how could I get the velocity with this given information?

Comment: Yes to W = -F*d in this case.  Use $\Delta K = W_{tot}$ to find the velocity of the two vehicles immediately after impact.  Use momentum conservation to determine the original velocity of the first vehicle.

Comment: Sir, I'm sorry but how to find the ΔK. ΔK means the difference between the two kinetic energies but in this case, I should add them because it is an inelastic collision. 
should I use this equation for ΔK? : V(m1+m2) ?

Comment: When the two collided vehicles are at rest, $K=0$.  You can then solve for the initial $K$ using the work energy equation quoted.

Comment: could you solve it with equations because I got so confused and I wanna cry rn, if you don't mind

Comment: how they would be collided and at rest at the same time? this is what confused me because he asked for the velocity after the impact

Comment: please Sir help me with my question

Comment: Sir, please solve it for me !

Comment: What you need to do is apply the work energy theorem. Check out the following. In particular, look at the car crash example. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/work.html Have fun.